# communication link failure in java

Tags: java, mysql

when i ll try to connecting mysql using jdbc means its succeessfully connected on localhost.but i replaced localhost by my ip address means itz not connected..y dis error is came..how it is cleared..help me.

dis is my coding:

```
package com.retrieve;
import java.sql.*;

public class retrieve{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
             System.out.println("Getting All Rows from a table!");
             Connection con = null;
             String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.249:3306/";
             String db = "login";
             String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
             String user = "root";
             String pass = "";
             try{
             Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, user, pass);
             try{
             Statement st = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  login");
             System.out.println("username: " + "\t" + "password: ");
             while (res.next()) {
                     String s = res.getString("username");
             String s1 = res.getString("password");
             System.out.println(s1 + "\t\t" + s);
             }
             con.close();
             }
             catch (SQLException s){
             System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
             }  
             }
             catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             }
             }
           }
```

The error is:

> Getting All Rows from a table!
>   java.sql.SQLException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Host '192.168.1.249' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:650)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1808)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:452)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
>       at com.retrieve.retrieve.main(retrieve.java:15)

Answer (score 0):

With your MySQL server you need to add permission for your user to be able to access your db from the specified IP

Execute following query from mysql console

```
GRANT ALL ON YOUR_DB.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.249';
```

Comment: allowing root access from remote host is not safe

Answer (score 0):

create user 'login'@'192.168.1.249' on your mysql server.

mysql builds users from 'name' (here - login you specified) and 'host' (address from which user connects to server). You can use '%' char to describe 'all hosts'.

consider reading this section of docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-account-management.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to close all the resources like `Statment`, `ResultSet` objects etc.Also, as @Jigar mentione, grant permission to the users as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check your port .If you changed your port number ,you got this error like
```

"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure"